# How to reflect chaining (ControlFlow) of Protractor (WebDriver) actions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webdriver, promise, protractor

In a protractor test it is possible to chain actions like "clear" and "sendKeys" on an Element like this:

```
element(by.id('myId')).clear().sendKeys('123456789')
```

I like the compact style of it. But why does it work?

According to the API Docs of [webdriver.Element.clear()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.clear)  the return type of clear() is `webdriver.promise.Promise.<void>`

When i compile it with TypeScript (1.8.x), the compiler complains that there is no property called `sendKeys()` on `Promise`. And I think that's actually the case.

I believe this works at runtime due to the [WebDriver ControlFlow Magic](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md).

How can i extend the [TypeScript Declaration File](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-protractor/angular-protractor.d.ts) of Protractor, to reflect this ControlFlow-Magic and make my TypeScript compiler happy?

Comment: Well, the correct return value is `this` which was added recently for explicitly chaining purposes. It needs to be a `Promise<void> AND this` as the return type, but assuming `this` is already a promise it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to the type `<any>` like so:

```
(<any> someInput.clear()).sendKeys()
```

Ugly, but works without the TS complaint.

Answer (score 0):

we ended up adding the function to the namespace like this

```
declare namespace webdriver.promise {
    interface Promise<T> {
        sendKeys(s: String);
    }
}
```